# Appending Elasticsearch Data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch indices with the same name as logstash-2015.12.10. on different servers, with different data. Now I want only Elasticsearch so there is the requirement of appending this data of both servers into one. 
Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy one index from one host to the same index on your other host using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html). Using the configuration below, make sure to replace the source and target hosts to match your host names.

**File: copylogs.conf**

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => "server1:9200"       <---- the host you want to copy from
   index => "logstash-2015.12.10"
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   host => "server2"       <--- the host you want to copy to
   port => 9200
   protocol => "http"
   manage_template => false
   index => "logstash-2015.12.10"
 }
}
```

And then you can simply launch it with

```
bin/logstash -f copylogs.conf
```

Comment: i have tried using this config but cant append the logs

Comment: What error do you get? Which version of logstash are you using?

Comment: it worked. Some security gro issues were there. It has been resolved now.