# Reindexing elastic search data from version 1.3.4 to 2.0.0

Tags: java, elasticsearch, reindex

I have data on elasticsearch server 1.3.4. I want to reindex data to server having version 2.0.0. using java api. Both versions require different Jars to make a connection to servers.
When I used jar of version 2.0 it failed to make connection to 1.3.4 and vice versa.

Any Idea how to do it ?

Comment: If you search for tools to export the data from your older version of elastic search and then import the data on your newer version, it might work out.

Comment: You could use logstash to copy from the host running 1.3.4 to the host running 2.0.0. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416009/appending-elasticsearch-data/34416218#34416218

Comment: yeah I could do that with http. But then I have to parse the response and then get documents out of it and send those to another cluster. I was looking for a way to do it via TCP or via transport client.

Comment: Provided your 1.3.4 schema is [compatible with 2.0.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.0.html#_elasticsearch_migration_plugin), you don't need to parse anything, Logstash with an elasticsearch input+output as shown in the linked answer above does the job perfectly without any need to write any code besides the Logstash config file.